# How to only show an option in my select and then show all of them with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i have a select with 5 options: Choose an option(default selection), level 1, level 2, level 3 and level 4.
First i only want to show the options: choose an option and level 1, and when i click the option level 1 show me only the option level 2 and when i choose the option level 2 show me the option level 3, etc etc.
i really dont know how to do it :( 

here is my code:

```
app.controller("myController", ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.niveles = [
    {id:1, "name": "Selecciona nivel"},
    {id:2, "name": "Nivel 1"},
    {id:3, "name": "Nivel 2"},
    {id:4, "name": "Nivel 3"}

];
$scope.nivelSeleccion = $scope.niveles[0];

$scope.table=['Table'];
$scope.rows=['Row'];
$scope.row=['Row'];
$scope.row.text = "Escribe un título";
$scope.counter = 1;

$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push('Row ' + $scope.counter);
    $scope.row.push('Row ' + $scope.counter);
    $scope.counter++;
}
```

}]);

---

```
<td>
   <select class="minimal" ng-model="nivelSeleccion"
   ng-options="nivel.name for nivel in niveles" ng-change="addRow()" ng-show="nivelSeleccion = niveles[0]" >
  </select>
                </td>
```

Comment: what you try do with `ng-show` here?

Comment: pretty confusing. could you try explain it again?

Comment: Im sorry english is not my first language, look you have a select box, and that select box have 5 options, but i want that when i choose one of that options, hide 3 of the others options and show me just one, like if i choose the option: LEVEL 1 then just leave me to choose the option LEVEL 2. i hope this help haha.

Comment: @Grundy i used that ng-show because when i select an option that option stays selected and i want it to get restarted and put the default selection of: "Select an option"

Answer (score 1):

i think its not possible with angular select,its for selecting the input from the drop-down.once u select the input has been taken.can u make your requirement simple so that we can help out

Answer (score 1):

[ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow/) doesn't manipulate the contents of your select box, but rather evaluates an expression to see if it is truthy, and if it is, it then shows/hides the element. So what you've initially written would show/hide the select based on the results of the expression `nivelSeleccion = niveles[0]`

If you want to show/hide table rows, then you can add the ng-show to the subsequent table rows.

```
<table>
<tr> <!--top row contains drop down list-->
    <td>
       <select class="minimal" ng-model="nivelSeleccion"
            ng-options="nivel.name for nivel in niveles" 
            ng-change="addRow()" />

    </td>
</tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index'
       ng-show="$index >= nivelSeleccion.id"><!--subsequent rows contain filtered results-->
        <td>{{row}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to remove options available in the select list, then you might have the function your ng-change uses pop/splice the `niveles` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ng-options 'disable when' to disable specific options. I was able to do what you're asking for with this:

```
<select class="minimal" ng-model="nivelSeleccion" ng-options="nivel.id as nivel.name disable when nivel.id > (nivelSeleccion + 1) for nivel in niveles" ng-change="addRow()"></select>
```

I removed the ng-show for this example.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write a watch for change on your ng-model value and alter the array inside the watch and rerender your site or:

Use the ngChange attribute and call a function that alters the array when you select an option.

You should hold the array twice in your controller in that case, in case you need to fall back or something.

Dont try to hide elements inside your input-dropdown, just alter the array.

Comment: This sounds pretty good but i dont know how to do it, can you please give me a basic example?